# Match only at string start or after whitespace

Tags: regex

I use regular expression to find hashtags in a string: `\B#[a-z0-9_-]+`.

I use `\B` because I want to match words which only starts with `#`, like `hello #there` and not like `hello#there`.

It works well and matches hashtags.
But it also wrongly matches those occurrences which has `#`, `@` or `$` symbols before `#`, like `##some`, `@#some` or `$#some`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my regex: https://regex101.com/r/spdAyj/2

Comment: I think you need [`(?<!\S)#[a-z0-9_-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/3B7lhL/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew cool, it works! But can you explain what does `(?<!\S)` means?

Comment: On the left, there must be a whitespace or start of string - is that the requirement?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since there must be a whitespace or start of string immediately to the left of the `#`, you may use a leading whitespace boundary:

```
(?<!\S)#[a-z0-9_-]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3B7lhL/1).

The `(?<!\S)` is a negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location. Basically, it is a shorter and more efficient (and more portable) version of `(?<=^|\s)` / `(?<=\A|\s)`.