# Regex: match a string at start or after some special characters

Tags: regex

I'm using Java Pattern class to find a string "keyword" which is at the beginning of the string or after a character that is in a list of characters. For example, the list of characters is ' ' and '<', then:

```
match:
"keyword..."
"...<keyword..."
"... keyword..."

not match:
"...akeyword..."
```

I've tried all these:

```
"[^ <]keyword"
"[ <^]keyword"
"[\\^ <]keyword"  note:for a Java/C# string backslash need to be escaped
```

This question is similar [Match only at string start or after whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687910/match-only-at-string-start-or-after-whitespace) but with only basic skills of Regex I can't adopt it to this problem. I'v tried:

```
"(?<!\\S<)keyword"
"(?<!([\\S<]))keyword"
```

And this seems to be a very basic problem, there may be a very easy and clear way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work `(^|[< ])keyword`

`(...|...)` has `^` and `[< ]`, stating either it should be start of string of be after `char(<)` or `char( )`

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alternation `|` in a non capturing group `(?:^|[ <])` to assert either the start of the string `^` or match a space or `<` in a character class and use a capturing group for keyword.

```
(?:^|[ <])(keyword)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LrqtNG/1)

Or you could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=...)` and match only keyword

```
(?<=^|[< ])keyword\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AGk5vY/1)

Comment: Remove \b to match "...<keywords..."

Comment: @jw_ You can remove the \b in that case or use `keywords?\b` to make the s optional.

Comment: non capturing group is great. Got it after a bug due to captured unwanted ' ' or '<'.

Comment: With Java Pattern.compile/Pattern.matcher/Matcher.find/Matcher.start/Matcher.end, why the result of "(?:^|[ <])(keyword)" still contains '<'?

Comment: You have to get the first capturing group. Else use the second pattern to het the match only.

Comment: The lookbehind without a word boundary https://regex101.com/r/JbD8qk/1

Answer (score 0):

```
(^keyword |[< ^]keyword)
```

Write in the square brackets the character you need.